# Mock entire client class with pytest

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I have a class that inherits from another class in which we build a client:

```
class Client(ClientLibrary):

    def __init__(self, hosts=[{'host':<HOST_ADDRESS>, 'port':<PORT>}], **kwargs):
        ''' alternative constructor, where i'd pass in some defaults to simplify connection'''
        super().__init__(hosts, *args, **kwargs)


    def some_method(self):
        ...
```

I want to test this class, and already have a test server set up that I want to connect to for testing. My initial approach was to create a MockClient that inherits from the original Client but swaps out the `hosts` parameter for the test host like so:

```
# I create a mock client that inherits from the original `Client` class, but passes in the host and port of the test server.

class MockClient(Client):

    def __init__(self, hosts=[{'host':MOCK_HOST, 'port':MOCK_PORT}]):

        super().__init__(hosts=hosts)
```

The idea was then that i'd use this mock client in the tests, however I have faced a lot of issues where I am testing functions that encapsulate the original `Client` class. I have tried patching it but keep on running into issues.

Is there a better way to approach this? And can this be done using pytest fixtures?

I want to be able to perform the following sorts of tests:

```
class TestFunctionThatUtilisesClient:

     def test_in_which_class_is_constructed_explicitly(self):
         client = Client()
         r = client.some_method()
         assert r == 'something'

    
     def test_in_which_class_is_constructed_implicitly(self):
         r = another_method() # Client() is called somewhere in here
         assert r == 'something else'
```

Comment: If you have a server for the real client to connect to, I'm not sure why you want to mock anything.

Comment: It's because the client is for a database, and I have a separate test database that I want to run tests against, rather than modifying the production database. Does that answer your question?

Comment: The test database is located on a different server, for clarification.

Comment: Yes, so use the regular client, but supply the correct host name for the tests. If your real code is *hard-coding* the production database name, then you've found your first bug in the code. Don't do that: make it a configuration option that you can specify differently in production and in your tests.

Comment: I see, i'm new to mocking and seem to have conflated the issue. What you've said makes total sense - thanks.